# IE reports incorrect .height() on content added after pageload

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm implementing an infinite-scroll, which means I'm appending chunks of content into the DOM (via jquery and javascript).

To make this feel smooth for the user, we need to do some manual scrolling to keep the content window "in the same place", especially as we prepend text in front of what the user is seeing. To accomplish this (prepend a chunk, then scroll the content down by the exact amount we prepended) we need to be able to determine the HEIGHT of the content we just prepended.  This is where Firefox and IE differ.  Firefox handles this correctly, and scrolls to the correct place in my content, but IE is reporting about 600px as the height when the true value is around 2400px.

```
var h1 = $(document).height(); //take the height before appending
$('#textChunks').prepend(newContent); // prepend stuff on top
var h2 = $(document).height();//take the height again...
alert(h2-h1);
```

The alerted value is consistently wrong in IE (off by a factor of 3), and it's consistent no matter how I take the measurement (I could instead measure the height of the 'newContent' after it's in the DOM and IE still reports it wrong, but consistently).  Even other 'built in' javascript functions such as .scrollIntoView() seem to be off by exactly this amount in IE.

As a sanity check, I can create a stand-alone html file on my desktop with a sample of my content, and in this situation it works.  So the problem seems to be only with content added after the pageload.

Comment: For what it's worth, it sounds like you have a css issue where the box module is shorter.  Another issue could be a missing closing tag, or, well there is no code so 50 places to guess.  I'd be left wounding why there was such a dif in value and that may be cause your css is not correctly accounting for the box module in borwsers that don't auto correct for you.  Just a thought.

Comment: Question:  Is your page in strict mode or quirks mode?  What `doctype` are you using and is that doctype the very first thing at the top of your HTML?  IE often does really weird things in quirks mode that are best forgotten about....

Comment: thank you sir!  this was the right direction indeed!  more details below

Comment: *Psst, Leo.  You are allowed to flag your own answer as the accepted one.*

Comment: thanks, i had to wait a day since i'm a newb!  :)  i've been lurking on this wonderful website for years (been developing almost a decade) but only just made my account.  I appreciate help, esp with formatting of questions and etiquette.  thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is QUIRKS MODE!

a great reference: http://webdesign.about.com/cs/doctype/a/aaquirksmode.htm

as a quick test, I changed my local settings (F12 in IE, and then change the 'Document Mode' from Quirks to IE9 standard), which fixed my scrolling issue!

Without the doctype declaration, IE was defaulting to quirks mode which apparently makes it report incorrect heights on elements added to the DOM after pageload, which naturally makes scrolling unreliable.  Also note that i was working in a frame inside a frame inside a frame, so the best place to specify the DOCTYPE for my content was in the OUTERMOST FRAME.

Comment: You'll want to specify the `doctype` in both the top level and the iframe, and you'll want them to be the same.  In some browsers the iframe inherits from the outmost frame, in other browsers, the local type type rules.

Answer (score 0):

use HTMLElement.offsetHeight to get the "real" height of any HTMLElement.

Comment: thanks, but I have tried several means of accessing this value, and they are all consistent and consistenly wrong (in IE only), whereas they are correct in Firefox.  IE reports the sizes of my divs to only be a fraction of their true value when I append these divs into the DOM.